# Is there an R-package to make a spatial 3D visualization of layers, including the subsurface?

Tags: r, 3d, gis, rayshader

I want to make a 3D map of a specific sampling site, having the digital terrain model in 3D at the top and add additionally soil layers in their corresponding depth in the subsurface- simliar to what mineral deposit maps look like, but in 3D and R.

It would be nice to additionally add a Canopy Height Model and to have the ability of getting crosssections and interacitvly scroll through the landscape. But at first I would appreciate general suggestions.

I looked up different packages. rayshader seemed best suitable for me, but as far as i see there was no possibility to visualize the subsurface in detail.

There might be other GIS software, which can handle it more easily- i would love to work in R, but i take other suggestions as well.

Comment: Hi @Annika_, Have you looked at the lidR and lidRviewer packages?  While developed primarily for lidar point cloud data processing and visualization, they provide 3D views of the point cloud and allow you to add layers.

Comment: I worked with it for lidar data once. Although the 3d viewer in fact is handy (but very slow in plotting), generating a new 3D model for visualization seems quite complicated and hard to adjust. But if there is no other possibility I could give it a try.